# is there a document specification for HWP (Hancom Word's file format)?

Tags: c++, xml, file, ms-word, file-processing

It would be of great help to know if there a document specification available for HWP (Hancom Word Format) which could help me to implement a HWP file Reader !

The data inside the file is encrypted, and so I am unable to make-out anything by just extracting a .HWP sample file.

I used `"Compound File Explorer"` as well as `"Structured Storage Explorer"` but couldn't make out any useful information from it.

Can anyone help please ? (Any piece of information would be useful for me) !

**The sample file can be downloaded from [here](https://easyupload.io/5p7val)**

Great Thanks !

Comment: Please do a minimum of research before asking questions. Two minutes of Googling brought me to [this page](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/HWP), [this LibreOffice bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90513) and [this vulnerability report with an overview of the file format](https://vulners.com/talos/TALOS-2017-0320).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link is the official website for HWP format.

https://www.hancom.com/etc/hwpDownload.do?gnb0=269&gnb1=271

Unfortunately, I could not find any document written in English. Even though I tried switching language from Korean to English which is in the bottom-right of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the link John ! good try. Just wanted to know if you came across something which helps me to open/understand this file (something like File Explorer as I mentioned in the question) where I could see all the tags, and buffer related to which I can map in the HWP specification. BR !

Comment: Hello user2008585, Hancom provides a free HWP viewer for users. If what you just want is just opening .HWP, you can visit Hancom and download Hancom's office viewer here: https://www.hancom.com/global/cs_center/csDownload.do    See Details for supported format for the Viewer you're about to download.